# Please help me to fix CSS of profile page on my site

Tags: css

I am not sure why the about field on my site, sailing down in IE7 (see http://img.skitch.com/20090629-t8mcp6tffd8kpwxrbk1rchc6wu.jpg). (It looks fine in FF for example). Who can suggest a way to fix it?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://j-in.org.ua:9000/account/login
2. Login using data (login: test, pass: test)
3. You will see same as on attached image :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you need to have two columns just have a containing section and place two floating divs inside of them then they will sit together and you can adjust either to your liking.

## content {

```
clear: both;
width: 950px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
background:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

## contentLeft {

```
float: left;
display:inline;
width: 630px;
margin: 10px;
background:#fff;
```

}

## contentRight {

```
float: right;
width: 270px;
margin-top:25px;
margin-right:15px;
background:#d7e5f7;
```

}

Obviously you will need to adjust the size of the columns to suit your site as well as colours etc but that should do it. You also need to make sure that your ContentLeft and ContentRight widths do not exceed the Contents width (including margins).